# Can't deserialize json file in Xamarin Forms

Tags: json, xamarin.forms

I have this json file

```
    
    "intro": {
        "_id": "61dbee7f1976f84d6d4c8292",
        "text": [ [ "text" ] ],
        "order": 0,
        "time": 60,
        "__v": 0
    },
    "main": [
        {
            "_id": "61dbee07086d18d8386a9335",
            "text": [ [ "text" ] ],
            "order": 1,
            "time": 90,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "61dbed78449d834314f1e3a1",
            "text": [ [ "text" ] ],
            "order": 1,
            "time": 90,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "61dbee572c5ac2cbe7101437",
            "text": [
                [ "text", "text" ],
                [ "text", "text" ]
            ],
            "order": 1,
            "time": 60,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "end": {
        "_id": "61dbee9c06e36b94c09d8b51",
        "text": [
            [ "text", "text" ],
            [ "text", "text" ]
        ],
        "order": 2,
        "time": 90,
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I tried using these classes

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Exercises
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string[,] text { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public int time { get; set; }
        public int __v { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class UpperEx
    {
        public List<Exercises> intro { get; set; }
        public List<Exercises>[] main { get; set; }
        public List<Exercises> end { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Root
    {
        public List<UpperEx> list { get; set; }
    }
```

And deserialize it like this with Newtonsoft.Json

```
Root ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
```

It doesn't seem to work. I either get "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List1" exeption or nothing happens.

What classes should I use?

Comment: your json is a single `UpperEx` object, not a list of them

Comment: Thanks, now I get it!

Answer (score 0):

Wise man, Jason, helped me in the comments.

Classes like these work:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Exercises
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string[,] text { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public int time { get; set; }
        public int __v { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class UpperEx
    {
        public Exercises intro { get; set; }
        public Exercises[] main { get; set; }
        public Exercises end { get; set; }
    }
```

And deserialization looks like this:

```
UpperEx ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpperEx>(result);
```